# React horizontal scrolling menu by sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple react App [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-forked-fu11q?file=/src/index.js) (fork).

I use [react-horizontal-scrolling-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu) for navigation.

So, now Menu scrolls. Anchor links work. If you scroll through the menu, the sections will scroll.

**But** If you scroll through the sections, the menu will not scroll and the active class of the menu will not switch.

```
<ScrollMenu
            ref={this.scrollRef}
            data={menu}
            transition={+transition}
            onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
            onSelect={this.onSelect}
            selected={selected}
            translate={translate}
            alignCenter={alignCenter}
            scrollToSelected={true}
            dragging={dragging}
            clickWhenDrag={clickWhenDrag}
            wheel={wheel}
          />
        </div>
    
{list.map((category) => (
          <div
            key={category.name}
            id={`${category.name.replace(/\s+/g, "")}`}
            className="section mb-4"
          >
            <h2>
              {category.name} {selected}
            </h2>
          </div>
        ))}
```

**Question:** How, when scrolling through sections, add the active class of the menu and scroll the menu to the active class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and move the wheel event add/remove event listener in order to make your codesandbox useable. It was adding a new wheel handler on each update and quickly became unusable, very laggy.

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to observe (*spy*) when the sections come into view and set the `selected` state using the target element's `id` attribute.

1. Create an array of element refs

   ```
   elmentRefs = list.map(React.createRef);
   ```
2. Create the observers

   ```
   createObservers = () => {
     const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
       (entries) => {
         entries.forEach((entry) => {
           if (entry.isIntersecting) {
             this.setState({ selected: entry.target.id });
           }
         });
       },
       { threshold: 1.0 } // <-- section fully in view
     );

     this.elmentRefs.forEach(({ current }) => observer.observe(current));
   };

   ...

   componentDidMount() {
     this.createObservers();

     ...
   }
   ```
3. Attach the refs to the sections

   ```
   {list.map((category, i) => (
     <div
       ref={this.elmentRefs[i]} // <-- attach element refs
       key={category.name}
       id={`${category.name.replace(/\s+/g, "")}`}
       className="section mb-4"
     >
       <h2>
         {category.name} {selected}
       </h2>
     </div>
   ))}
   ```

[image: Edit react-horizontal-scrolling-menu-by-sections]